# Any way to pass enum values by name as commandline args?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Is there any way to pass the value of an enum by name from the commandline? Rather what's the cleanest solution?

I tried the below,

```
typedef enum int unsigned { white, black, red } colour_e;
class house;

  rand colour_e colour;

  string n_colour = "white";

  constraint c_colour {
    colour.name() == n_colour;
  }

endclass: house

program top;

  house paradise;

  initial begin
    paradise = new();
    void'($value$plusargs("colour=%0s", paradise.n_colour));
    if (!paradise.randomize())
      $display("not randomized");
    else   
      $display("paradise.colour = %s",paradise.colour);
  end

endprogram: top
```

I would want to pass something like this `+colour=black`. so that the paradise.colour is assigned black.

vcs cribbed for using `enum.name()` in the constraints.

below is the error.

> Error-[NYI-CSTR-SYS-FTC] NYI constraint: sys function calls
>   T-enum_1.sv, 9 $unit, "this.colour.name"   System function calls are
>   not yet implemented in constraints.   Remove the function call or if
>   possible replace it with an integral state   variable assigned in
>   pre_randomize().

while Riviera cried as below

> ERROR VCP7734 "Type of 'this.colour.name()' is not allowed in a
>   constraint block. Only integral types are allowed in a constraint
>   block." "design.sv" 9  1 ERROR VCP7734 "Type of 'n_colour' is not
>   allowed in a constraint block. Only integral types are allowed in a
>   constraint block." "design.sv" 9  1 WARNING VCP7114 "STRING value
>   expected for format specifier %s as parameter
>   paradise.colour." "testbench.sv" 13  54

which brings the question to me, does everything in the contraint block has to be of integral type (just like we cannot declare a `string` as `rand` variable)?

ANyone wants to play around the code please have a look at the code at EDA playground [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Cn6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **uvm_enum_wrapper** class to do the conversion from string to corresponding enum value. It is a template class wrapper defined in uvm_globals.svh (part of UVM 1.2) and you can use it as follows:

```
typedef enum {white, black, red} colour_e;

typedef uvm_enum_wrapper#(colour_e) colour_wrapper;
string colour_str;
void'($value$plusargs("colour=%0s", colour_str));

colour_wrapper::from_name(colour_str, paradize.n_colour);
```

The wrapper class **uvm_enum_wrapper** works by traversing the enum entries and creating an assoc array for a enum[string] map for the given enum type (supplied as template parameter). For more details take a look at [the documentation](https://eda-playground.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_static/uvm-1.2/files/base/uvm_globals-svh.html#uvm_enum_wrapper#(T).from_name).

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution for the same. If you are not using UVM 1.2 version then there is like you can take string as an input argument and convert that string argument into int type. After that you can directly cast int to enum type by $cast.
Because there is no way to convert string to enum type (except UVM 1.2) so you have to add one extra step for the same.

```
module Test;

  typedef enum {black,red,blue} color_e; //enum declaration
  color_e color; //type of enum

  string cmd_str; //Commandline string input
  int cmd_int; //Input string is first converted into int

  initial
    begin
      $value$plusargs("enum_c=%0s",cmd_str); //Take input argument as string it may be 0,1 or 2
      cmd_int=cmd_str.atoi(); //Now convert that string argument into int type
      $cast(color,cmd_int); //Casting int to enum type
      $display("Value of color is  --> %p",color); //Display value of enum
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: This won't work. I think you either misunderstood the question or the way atoi works.

As per the IEEE Std 1800-2012 standard,

_str.atoi() returns the integer corresponding to the ASCII decimal representation in str. For
example:
str = "123";
int i = str.atoi(); // assigns 123 to i.
The conversion scans all leading digits and underscore characters ( _ ) and stops as soon as it encounters any
other character or the end of the string. It returns zero if no digits were encountered._

Please refer to 
[http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Mxt]

Comment: What I want try to do is like you can pass int variable. In my example you can pass 0-black , 1-red or 2-blue from command line argument. because you pass it as string you have convert it into int and after that you can assign that int to your enum type.You can see my example with command line option +enum_c=0,1 or 2. You get your enum type in display.

Comment: If you are using  `atoi`  then you need to pass the digits (basically the numeric value) as a string, however my question was about passing a non-digit character  (here color name) alone as the plusarg value. If you have to pass the corresponding numeric value as a string, why would one want to pass it as a string in the first place?  It doesn't make sense to me as whole purpose of passing a string is that the end user doesn't need to remember the integer values.